# Why doesn't this conditional expression generate a SyntaxError?

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax-error, conditional-statements

When "if" is combined with "or", which one Python prioritize first:
for example:

```
if a == b or c
```

is it `(a == b) or c`  or is it `a == (b or c)`.
I assume the correct logical form should be the former one but I accidentally used:

```
if gender == "m' or "M"
```

and to my surprise, it did not generate any errors and did the purpose.

Comment: Question shows no research effort.  A simple SO or Google search would reveal the answer. Please read and follow the posting guidelines: what kinds of questions can I ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, and How to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Remember to also to include Minimal, complete, verifiable examples:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.  Then, click `edit` to edit your question so that we may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence):

> The following table summarizes the operator precedence in Python, from
>   lowest precedence (least binding) to highest precedence (most
>   binding).
>
> ```
> lambda
> if – else 
> or    
> and
> not x 
> in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==  
> ...
> ```

So, to answer your question,

```
a == b or c
```

Is equivalent to

```
(a == b) or (c)
```

---

The code `if gender == "m" or "M"` will work like this: Is `gender == 'm"`? If yes, the result is `True`. Otherwise, test the "truthiness" of `"M"`. Is `"M"` "true"? If it is, the result is true. To understand how this works, you should know that all objects have a truthiness associated to it. All non-zero integers, non-empty strings and data structures are `True`. `0`, `0.0`, `''`, `None`, `False`, `[]`, `{}` and `set()` are all `False`.

For more details, visit [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: Thank you, It is what seems logic to me and I have always used. But could you please explain how did what I used in my code work:

Comment: @COLDSPEED: Thank you again. I appreciate such a clear explanation.